# Set slider size of QScrollBar correspond with content

Tags: c++, qt, scrollbar

I am doing a software with a drawing surface that represent a plot (like a sin function) (A child of QWidget) and I would like to have a QScrollBar acting like a QScrollArea. So if my drawing widget show show 750 dots (my plot is made of dots), but there are 1000 dots, I would like the slider of the ScrollBar to fill 75% of the available space.

I can't use a QScrollArea because the scroll is proportionnal with the size of the widget it contains. In my case, the scroll must be proportionnal with the number of dots on the screen. I know how to get my ratio, but I don't know how to setup correctly the QScrollBar

Example: I edited the value of PageStep, but I don't understand how this work. I can set pageStep to 100 with a range of [0,99] and it will fill the half of the QScrollBar.

My interface:

```
QWidget (Vertical Layout) //Main Widget
    Drawing Surface (Child of QWidget)
    QScrollBar (Horizontal)
```

Comment: It's unclear why you can't use `QScrollArea`. "the scroll is proportional with the size of the widget it contains" - what does it mean? Please provide some example, may be a picture.

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear, as you can see on this link (http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/widgets-imageviewer.html), if you see the picture at the center is too much big and only 80% of the picture is shown. The horizontal scroll bar is sized to represent that 80%. But in my case, thoses proportions are not from the picture size, but from an other value provided by my software.

Comment: Just create a widget that contains all 1000 dots and put this widget into a scroll area. Scrollbars will be managed automatically. Or there are too many dots and you are worrying about efficiency, aren't you?

Comment: Yep, if the size of a dot is one byte, I can have a lot of data like a size of 4 Gigabyte, so display every dot is not possible

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think I am able to do something with this:

http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qscrollbar.html

[image]

> The relationship between a document length, the range of values used in a scroll bar, and the page step is simple in many common situations. The scroll bar's range of values is determined by subtracting a chosen page step from some value representing the length of the document. In such cases, the following equation is useful: document length = maximum() - minimum() + pageStep().

So in my case the length is the number of dots and I can set minimum() to 0. So, as you can see on the picture, to do something like QScrollArea. The proportion is: PercentageVisible = PageStep / Length and another equation is Length = PageStep + Max.

I have two equations, two missing values (PageStep and Maximum) and two known values (PercentageVisible and Length).

Example: I have 1024 dots, but only 75% of them are shown.

0.75 = PageStep / 1024 ----------> PageStep = 768

1024 = Max + 768 ----------------> Max = 256

You can try it in your software and it will works. I know there's not so much people that will needs to reproduce this because QScrollArea will do the job in most of the case.

By example, this code is in a slot reacting from a resize event:

```
ui.sbarRange->setPageStep(u64SampleCount * dRatio);
ui.sbarRange->setMaximum(u64SampleCount - ui.sbarRange->pageStep());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new QWidget subclass and reimplement `sizeHint` and `paintEvent`. In the `paintEvent` you can use `event->rect()` to determine which area is currently exposed and needs to be drawn. Note that `paintEvent` must be fast if you don't want your window to freeze. Also you need to put created widget in `QScrollArea`.

Here is a simple example that draws a sinusoid:

```
class SinWidget : public QWidget {
public:
  QSize sizeHint() const {
    return QSize(10000, 200);
  }

  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    for(int x = event->rect().left(); x <= event->rect().right(); x++) {
      painter.drawPoint(x, 100.0 + qSin(0.05 * x) * 20.0);
    }
  }
};

QScrollArea area;
area.setWidget(new SinWidget());
area.show();
```

This example will work fine with very large widget size (e.g. 100 000 pixels). So full repaint or memory allocation doesn't happen. You only need to keep your `paintEvent` fast.

Comment: I don't have any problem with paintEvent (was already done), but sizeHint doesn't change anything. My ScrollBar are disabled. If I set "Widget resizable" to false (it uses the default size of 400x300) and reduce the dialog below the widget size, the scrollbar become visible.

Comment: By default scrollbars become visible if content length is larger than viewport length. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: I want it to do something like that, but I would like the size to react with the dots and not with the size. I would like to do something like QScrollArea, but not exactly the same