# How to change design of QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to set the width of `QTextEdit` slider.
How make it bigger?
I use last version qt on Windows.

Comment: This should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432534/set-slider-size-of-qscrollbar-correspond-with-content

Comment: To the closers: this is a genuine question. Since the answer is a one-liner, there's really nothing much to "show" for prior solutions. The asker simply didn't stumble upon stylesheets. That's within reason, IMHO. There's truly nothing to show unless you already know the answer. I mean, come on, what would have *you* tried, hmm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [StyleSheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar).

```
myTextEdit->setStyleSheet("QScrollBar:vertical {width: 20px;}")
```